# Oracle RAC instance fail

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac

I use the Oracle database 11gr2, and it is a RAC environment that has two instances. One day, one instance failed when the hardware failed. The client uses the `tnsnames.ora` which has two IP addresses to connect to, but it still can't connect to the database and gets some errors. So I want to know if it is the fault that the client didn't write the code to reconnect or it is the fault that the Oracle RAC configuration didn't automatically change the connection to the other instance?

Comment: don't you have a load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a mistake in the RAC setup, and possibly the `tnsnames.ora` file.  As long as the application was connecting to a service name in `tnsnames.ora` then Oracle RAC should have handled the switchover to the other node.